# How to use a partial within Devise sign-up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My Devise sign-up form contains more than a simple email. It includes 8 fields and a drop-down. I'd like to use a partial to define the layout only once for sign-up ad user profile update. So I created the partial which looks like:

```
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :login %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :login, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the "new.html.erb" view, which looks like:

```
<% provide(:title, t('Registration')) %>

<h2>Please sign up</h2>

<div class="container">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <%= render "devise/shared/user", locals: {f: f}%>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="actions">
          <br/>
          <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Unfortunately, the f variable is not passed to the partial; I get this error:

```
 Showing /home/fred/55Projets/development/Stairs/app/views/devise/shared/_user.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007fa656e26f90>:0x007fa6448a34e0>

Extracted source (around line #4):        


2      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
3       <div class="field">
4         <%= f.label :login %><br />
5          <%= f.text_field :login, autofocus: true %>
6        </div>
7      </div>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing it directly

```
<%= render "devise/shared/user", f: f %>
```